# How to have msysgit use the terminal for `--help`?

Tags: git, msysgit, msys, manpage

When I enter command such as `git config --help`, instead of showing help directly I end up with a browser-launch showing an HTML help. While that surely looks fancy, it's usually not what I want. So how can I have msysgit's help behave just the way it does on Linux?

Comment: `git help help` worth looking into

Answer (score 0):

Git has it's own tool called **[`git web--browse`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-web--browse)** that invokes the web-browser.
Set the environment **[`GIT_TRACE`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#Debugging)** to see what processes are started, and with what 
command-lines.

So that can help debugging the issue.

> A workaround can be to rename/delete all `git-<command>.html` files so git will not find them